# ImportError when importing scipy.stats, undefined symbol (scipy version 0.14.0)

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, importerror, python-import

I just upgraded to Scipy 0.14.0 and Ubuntu 14.04. Now when I try to import stats I get an ImportError.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/Documents/test/importTest/importScipy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.stats as stats
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 334, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 181, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 548, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/basic.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import orthogonal
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/orthogonal.py", line 90, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/blas.py", line 145, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so: undefined symbol: clange_
```

Comment: How did you install scipy?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing from source solved the issue.

First download the numpy and scipy tarballs.

Then locate the BLAS and LAPACK *.so files on my machine. I found them in /usr/lib/. If they are not there you can install them. I used the standard Ubuntu finder to locate them:

```
find -iname 'libblas.so'
find -iname 'liblapack.so'
```

So I set some environment variables for the installation.

```
export BLAS=/usr/lib/libblas.so
export LAPACK=/usr/lib/liblapack.so
```

Then I downloaded the source tarballs of numpy and scipy, untarred the tarball and then installed by cd into the install directories and

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

NOTE: You may want to specify the install directory.

Comments welcome. Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to `Scipy` missing proper reference to `LAPACK`. I followed the instructions suggested by @jtorca and found that you don't even need to install via tarballs. For me, the following did the trick:

```
apt-get install libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev
export BLAS=/usr/lib/libblas.so
export LAPACK=/usr/lib/liblapack.so
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
```